# How can I format a python logger which is defined in one class but calls itself from another class?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have an internal logging library which I consume to run my service. The library provides 2 logging capabilities, one for standard and one for debug. I want to log the filename and function name for the logger as well. Since the library does not provide that functionality, I modified the formatter. But I noticed that it is not working as expected. Please see below my expected output.

Here is the MWE

`one.py`

```
import logging
from logging import handlers
import datetime as dt
import time

class myFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    converter=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        ct = self.converter(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = ct.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            t = ct.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            z = time.strftime("%z")
            s = "%s.%03d %s" % (t, record.msecs, z)
        return s

class Logger:
    @staticmethod
    def get(name):
        logger = logging.getLogger("example")
        handler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler("example.log", mode='a', maxBytes=10485760)

        formatter = myFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        return logger
```

`two.py`

```
from one import Logger
from three import DebugLog

class Component(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        logname = name

        logger = Logger.get(logname)
        self.logger = logger

        self.debug = DebugLog(self)
```

`three.py`

```
class DebugLog:
    def __init__(self,component):
        self._component = component

    def _debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self._component.logger.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)

    def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self._debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

`main.py`

```
from two import Component
from one import myFormatter

component = Component('myexample')

# this is my modification
DEBUG_LOG_FORMAT = myFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s')

component.debug._component.logger.handlers[0].formatter = DEBUG_LOG_FORMAT

def component_log():
    component.logger.info("I log this in component log")

def component_debug_log():
    component.debug.debug("I log this in component debug log")

component_log()
component_debug_log()
```

Current output

```
➜  M-WR4R2NYKL6 ~/logging-bug python main.py
➜  M-WR4R2NYKL6 ~/logging-bug cat example.log
2023-11-03 10:45:16.450 +0530 INFO: [main.py:14 -        component_log() ] I log this in component log
2023-11-03 10:45:16.450 +0530 DEBUG: [three.py:8 -               _debug() ] I log this in component debug log
```

Expected output

```
2023-11-03 10:45:16.450 +0530 INFO: [main.py:14 -        component_log() ] I log this in component log
2023-11-03 10:45:16.450 +0530 DEBUG: [main.py:17 -  component_debug_log() ] I log this in component debug log
```

I can control only `main.py` and not the other files because I do not own them. I can maybe modify them by inheriting or monkey patching them but cannot change them at source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can control only `main.py` and not the other files because I do not own them.

What about extending  `DebugLog` to override `debug()`? That way you can use `inspect` module to get the caller's context and use it:

```py
import inspect
from two import Component, DebugLog
from one import myFormatter

class MyDebugLog(DebugLog):
    def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        # Update lambda to accept two arguments: stack_info and stacklevel
        self._component.logger.findCaller = lambda stack_info=None, stacklevel=None: (caller_frame.f_code.co_filename, caller_frame.f_lineno, caller_frame.f_code.co_name, None)
        super().debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
        self._component.logger.findCaller = logging.getLoggerClass().findCaller


component = Component('myexample')

# Use our logger instead
component.debug = MyDebugLog(component)

DEBUG_LOG_FORMAT = myFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s')
component.debug._component.logger.handlers[0].formatter = DEBUG_LOG_FORMAT

def component_log():
    component.logger.info("I log this in component log")

def component_debug_log():
    component.debug.debug("I log this in component debug log")

component_log()
component_debug_log()
```

Comment: This might work, I can see this bug `File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 1622, in _log
    fn, lno, func, sinfo = self.findCaller(stack_info, stacklevel)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: MyDebugLog.debug.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Comment: Please also include what the change is being done with inspect module. I'm not that exposed to inspect module.

Comment: The signature of `findCaller()` changed  in 3.11 and I assumed you are on older version. I updated the answer

Comment: That worked. Thank you.